# Put json data into table

Tags: json, angular

I actually want to create a table with the data who the api return to me.
The problem is that i can't print the data.
The IdLangage have his column in the table and i want to put the data of the traduction into the correct cell.
The JSON data format :

```html
traductionData ={
"Data":
  [
    {
      "Code": "BJR",
      "TraductionsFormat":
        [{
          "Code": "BJR",
          "Description": null,
          "Id": 0,
          "IdLangage": "FR",
          "Traduction": "Bonjour"
        },
        {
          "Code": "BJR",
          "Description": null,
          "Id": 0,
          "IdLangage": "EN",
          "Traduction": "Hello"
        }]
    },
  ] };
```

Here is my table where i want to print the data into :

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="25%">Code</th>
      <th width="15%">FR</th>
      <th width="15%">EN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let traduction of traductionData">
      <td>{{ traduction.TraductionsFormat.Code }}</td>
      <td>{{ traduction.TraductionsFormat.Traduction}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my angular service :

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  localUrlAPI: string = environment.urlAPI;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  getAllTraductions(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.localUrlAPI+"GetAllTraductionsGroupByCode")
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
      console.log(res);
    }))
  }
}
```

And here is my angular Component with my http request :

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-edit-traductions',
  templateUrl: './grid-edit-traductions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-edit-traductions.component.scss']
})
export class GridEditTraductionsComponent implements OnInit {

  traductionData !: any[];

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLesTraductions();
  }

  getLesTraductions(){
    this.api.getAllTraductions()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      this.traductionData = res.Data;
      console.log(this.traductionData)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: So what issue did you saw now ?

Comment: This actually don't print me anything in the table

Comment: Does the ```console.log(this.traductionData)``` show proper data in console?

Comment: Yes i can see the data into the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th *ngFor="let column of tableHeaders">
      {{column}}
     </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng *ngFor="let row of tableRows">
  <td *ngFor="let column of tableHeaders">
    {{row[column]}}
    <ng-container *ngFor="let trad of row.TraductionsFormat, let j = index">
      <span *ngIf="row.TraductionsFormat[j].IdLangage === column">
        {{row.TraductionsFormat[j].Traduction}}
      </span>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the ts:

```
tableRows: Array<any> = [];
tableHeaders: Array<any> = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
//---- TABLE HEADERS -----
this.tableHeaders.push("Code")
this.traductionData.Data.forEach(el => {
  el.TraductionsFormat.map(c => c.IdLangage).forEach(lang => {
    this.tableHeaders.push(lang);
  })
});
this.tableHeaders = [...new Set(this.tableHeaders)];
//---- TABLE ROWS -----
this.traductionData.Data.forEach(el => {
  this.tableRows.push(el)
});
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajrtvq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: That return me this error : Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: @KylianTR I updated the answer with the formatted json data

Comment: We can't used the json format that i used?

Comment: As @abellay said in your JSON data there are missing commas and brackets.
After TraductionsFormat you open a square bracket but you dont close it and inside Data (wich is an array) the items must be separated by a comma.

Comment: I updated my json data, can you watch it

Comment: Ok now makes much more sense I'll update my answer

Comment: I updated the answer, pls mark the answer as correct if this solves the problem, thanks

Comment: The problem is that i have a lot of more translations in my json file, and sometimes the english or the french translation is not present also this solution can't worked correctly

Comment: I can't make a link IdLangage - Traduction where i link all the english Translations on EN and all the french translations on FR and call {{ EN }} / {{ FR }} in my html file?

Comment: ok so you want create something more dynamic....I'll try something else later. 
English and France are the only languages?

Comment: Actually there is : French, English, Dutch, Spanish, German, but later languages ​​can be added, everything must be dynamic, np take your time, thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @KylianTR I updated the answer let me know if is ok

Comment: That return me this error : Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: @KylianTR I added a stackblitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajrtvq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data you've provided is wrong, there are missing commas and brackets. Although, I'm pretty sure that the reason the data isn't shown in table is that the `"TraductionsFormat"` is an array. If you want to get an item from array you have to provide an index.

```
<tr *ngFor="let traduction of traductionData">
      <td>{{ traduction.TraductionsFormat[0].Code }}</td>
      <td>{{ traduction.TraductionsFormat[0].Traduction}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Above is just simple solution. You might want to use dynamic indexes.

Comment: The data now appear, all the translations appear in the same column but i want that the french translation appear only in the column : "FR" and the english translations appear in the column : "EN". How can i do that? thank you for your reply